# Why some urls of my website show nginx 404 instead of the website 404 page

Tags: nginx, https, httprequest

After passing some SEO test, I figured out that in the middle of a report about 404 pages, I have some urls which stopped on the nginx 404 page instead of going through my django hand-made 404 page.

For example, I don't understand why this url:
`mydomain.org/en/%20`

will have a nginx 404 error instead of redirecting normally (as a standard space would do instead of the %20) to the main page.

Same go for this:
`example.org/en/%20-%20download`

For more explanation, the nginx error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /en/ was not found on this server.

And of course back-end logs / network shows nothing more.

Does someone have a clue about it and could share some knowledge?
Is there some process to "fix" this behaviour?

Comment: The problem is likely in your nginx configuration, but you didn't show it to us.

Comment: Oh ok, so it's not something specific to the urls in general. Thanks!